# HAVING Clause in Group Query doesn’t work

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my database I have two tables: `tblReceipts` and `tblDisclosure`. Some business details:

1. Sometimes I receive money but don’t have a disclosure to apply it to.
2. Sometimes I process a disclosure before I receive payment.

The following query is intended to return all instances of 1 and 2, but it doesn’t. I get no records and yet I know one such instance exists. When I run the query I get a request to input data in parameter `Test`. If I remove the `HAVING` clause the query correctly returns all records. How can I apply a filter as needed?

```
SELECT
    Sum([DBSFee] + [MyFee]) AS Fee,
    [Amount] + [Adjustment] AS Rec,
    tblReceipts.ID,
    [Fee] - [Rec] AS Test,
    tblClient.ClientName,
    tblClient.ClientID,
    tblReceipts.Notes
FROM
    (tblDisclosure
    INNER JOIN tblReceipts ON tblDisclosure.ReceiptsLookup = tblReceipts.ID)
    INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
GROUP BY
    [Amount] + [Adjustment],
    tblReceipts.ID,
    tblClient.ClientName,
    tblClient.ClientID,
    tblReceipts.Notes
HAVING Test <> 0;
```

Comment: INNER JOINS are commutative -- why put the parenthesis in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Select Fee, Rec, ID, Test, ClientName, ClientID, Notes FROM (
SELECT Sum([DBSFee]+[MyFee]) AS Fee, [Amount]+[Adjustment] AS Rec, tblReceipts.ID, [Fee]-[Rec] AS Test, tblClient.ClientName, tblClient.ClientID, tblReceipts.Notes
FROM (tblDisclosure INNER JOIN tblReceipts ON tblDisclosure.ReceiptsLookup = tblReceipts.ID) INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
GROUP BY [Amount]+[Adjustment], tblReceipts.ID, tblClient.ClientName, tblClient.ClientID, tblReceipts.Notes) as T
WHERE Test<>0;
```

Comment: Using your suggestion I get this: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Not Sum([DBSFee]+[MyFee]-Amount-Adjustment =0' as part of a aggregate function".

Comment: Where did that word "not" come from? Did you type "Not" in there?

Comment: Uhm, what about Having (Fee-Rec) <>0

Comment: Twice I did exactly what you said and didn't type the 'not'.

Comment: Having (Fee-Rec) <>0 makes no difference.